# Why is the function argument "x" is not checked for "undefined" when using "x?"?

Tags: coffeescript

[The following CoffeeScript code](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%0A%20%20foo%20=%20%28x%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20alert%28%22hello%22%29%20unless%20x?%0A%20%20%20%20alert%28%22world%22%29%20unless%20y?%0A%0A):

```
foo = (x) ->
  alert("hello") unless x?
  alert("world") unless y?
```

is compiled to:

```
var foo;

foo = function(x) {
  if (x == null) {
    alert("hello");
  }
  if (typeof y === "undefined" || y === null) {
    return alert("world");
  }
};
```

Why is `foo`'s argument `x` is not checked for `undefined`, while `y` is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The undefined check is to prevent the ReferenceError exception that's thrown when you retrieve the value of a nonexistent identifier:

```
>a == 1
ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

The compiler can see that the x identifier exists, because it's the function argument.

The compiler cannot tell whether the y identifier exists, and the check to see whether y exists is therefore needed.

```
// y has never been declared or assigned to
>typeof(y) == "undefined"
true
```

Comment: But, if `foo` is called without arguments, e.g. `bar = foo()`, wouldn't `x` be `undefined`?

Comment: Different meaning of undefined. If you call foo() or foo(undefined), then x === [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined). The identifier x exists (it's just set to a specific value), so you won't get a ReferenceError. The comparison will still work because undefined == null (note that it's using two equal signs, and not three).

Comment: `x == null` will fail if `x` is a completely unknown variable, whereas `typeof x` would return `"undefined"` in that case, even though `x` doesn't have the *value* `undefined`—it simply doesn't exist.